# p:button leads to ClassCastException

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I use Primefaces 2.2 together with Spring 3.0.5 and it is working pretty good so far but today I ran into the following problem. I wanted to include the p:button component but when I do that I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.primefaces.optimus.navigationhandler.ViewIdBasedNavigationHandler cannot be cast to javax.faces.application.ConfigurableNavigationHandler
    at org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.findNavigationCase(ButtonRenderer.java:114)
    at org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.buildOnclick(ButtonRenderer.java:90)
    at org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(ButtonRenderer.java:56)
    at org.primefaces.component.button.ButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(ButtonRenderer.java:38)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at ...
```

The ViewIdBasedNavigationHandler is configured in my faces-config.xml and all other primefaces components have been working so far. As far as I see the ViewIdBasedNavigationHandler class is derived from javax.faces.application.NavigationHandler and not from javax.faces.application.ConfigurableNavigationHandler so the ClassCastException makes sense. But due to the fact that I cannot find other users having the same problem I guess I am missing something.

Any ideas?
Jens

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ViewIdBasedNavigationHandler, I suggest removing it or old optimus project if you have it. JSF 2.0 has view id based implicit navigation built-in.

Comment: Ok, I removed the declaration and the dependency to optimus. Now now redirects like this do not work anymore: 
<p:commandButton value="New something" ajax="false"
 action="redirect:editSomething">
</p:commandButton>
The file exists (editSomething.xhtml). I still think that I am missing an essential configuration param.